Anchor Link Not Opening in *ngFor Directive
In my angular template I have an *ngFor directive that loops through a list of items and renders a link for each:
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <a href="{{ getLink(item) }}" target="_blank">
    {{ item.id }}
  </a>
</div>

I can right click on the links and open them in a new tab just fine, but when I left click them, nothing happens. Also, strangely, when I try to inspect the element, the developer console throws a warning message:
Node cannot be found in the current page.


I'm unclear as to why, but adding a TrackByFunction fixed the issue:
<div *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy:trackItemById">
  <a href="{{ getLink(item) }}" target="_blank">
    {{ item.id }}
  </a>
</div>

and then in my Angular TS code:
trackByItemId(index: number, item: Item) {
  return item.id;
}

I simplified this code by switching over to the Angular 17 control flow syntax, which means I could get rid of the trackByItemId function above:
@for (item of items; track item.id) {
  <div>
    <a href="{{ getLink(item) }}" target="_blank">
      {{ item.id }}
    </a>
  </div>
}

It should be noted that the control flow syntax also fails without the track item.id portion.

This is crystal ball divination, but it looks like without trackBy, the HTML structure inside ngFor is destroyed and re-rendered on each change detection cycle. When you try to click/inspect an element, change detection is triggered, and the element is removed (replaced by a new one), so it cannot be found on the page.
The reason may be, for example, that in each change detection cycle, the "items" array is generated anew, having different references.
Adding trackby id instructs angular not to compare items by reference, but by id.
Providing TS code/stackblitz would be helpful here.
